# PHP: Disambiguating Column Names on Join Using Mysqli

Tags: javascript, php, sql, json, mysqli

This issue relates to losing data due to conflicting column names in a JOIN. Specifically, using PHP's mysqli and returning the data as a JSON object.

Let's say you have two tables that are related to each other using another lookup table.

For example, let's say you have users:

```
user

id      name
---------------------
1       John Thomas
```

and recipes:

```
recipe

id     name
---------------------
15     Fried Chicken
```

and ownership/rights to these recipes is defined in a lookup table:

```
user_recipe

user   recipe
--------------
1      15
```

So, in this case, John Thomas has rights to view the Fried Chicken recipe.

Let's say you want to get a record with all of this data, so you construct a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `user_recipe`
  INNER JOIN `recipe`
    ON `recipe`.id = `user_recipe`.recipe
  INNER JOIN `user`
    ON `user`.id = `user_recipe`.user;
```

Now let's also say you're using PHP's mysqli object. Then you use `json_encode` and hand the data back to your javascript. Great! Except that the data looks like this:

```
{
    id:15,
    user:1,
    recipe:15,
    name:"Fried Chicken"
}
```

How do you resolve this issue? You could use aliases, but what if there are a lot more columns and you don't want to have to write them all out?

Comment: Do you really need to get ALL the columns from all the tables? Usually you only need a specific set of columns, and you can use aliases.

Comment: Usually you do only need a specific set. The case where I use this is in building an MVC framework where you want to be able to pull out "combined" data without knowing what all the column names are.

Comment: The other thing you can do is try to avoid using the same column names in different tables, unless they're foreign keys (since it doesn't matter which table they come from, they should be the same).

Comment: That is also a good idea. This isn't supposed to be a be all end all solution. It's just an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make use of mysqli's method `fetch_fields`, you can separate the data back into groups, or add prefixes to the field names, or whatever else you'd like.

Here's an example:

```
$sql = '...QUERY...';
$mysqli->query($sql);
$fields = $result->fetch_fields();
$output = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    $newoutput = array();
    foreach($row as $key=>$value)
    {
        if (is_numeric($key))
            $newoutput[$fields[$key]->table][$fields[$key]->name] = $value;
    }
    $output[] = $newoutput;
}
$result->free();
echo json_encode($output);
```

After doing that, the data will be handed back in this format:

```
{
    user_recipe:{
        user:1,
        recipe:15
    },
    user:{
        id:1,
        name:"John Thomas"
    },
    recipe:{
        id:15,
        name:"Fried Chicken"
    }
}
```

Of course, you can build the JSON object however you'd like.